# Como obter todos os ips associados a algum domínio com Python?

Tags: python, ip, domínio

Preciso criar uma aplicação que obtivesse todos os ips associados a algum domínio.
Tentei utilizar o seguinte código em Python:

```
import socket

print(socket.gethostbyname('facebook.com.br'))
```

Entretanto, apenas me retorna um IP. 
Teria alguma forma de fazer retornar o range do facebook, por exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você preferir uma opção que não use Python, pode-se usar Tracert no Windows, ou Traceroute no Linux.

> Saída do código em Tracert

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim você poderia usar o Python apenas para rodar o comando externo com o auxilio da biblioteca **subprocess**, ao invés de tentar usar os recursos da própria linguagem.

O código abaixo executa o comando e armazena em um arquivo .txt

```
# coding: UTF-8


import os
import subprocess


# Se for Windows, apenas troque o traceroute por tracert
command = ['traceroute', 'www.facebook.com']

with open('log.txt', 'w') as arq:
    output_command = subprocess.call(command, stdout=arq)

print('[+] Finished')
```

Comment: É uma boa dica. Mas, que tal produzir um exemplo de código que faça isso? Melhoraria muito a sua resposta (e ganha o meu +1)

Comment: Tens razão, editei a minha resposta. Obrigado pela sugestão, pois me fez pensar de uma forma diferente da que eu estava pensando...

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Gurion, acho o codigo abaixo poderá ajudalo:

```
import socket

lista_de_ip = []

site = socket.getaddrinfo("www.facebook.com.br" ,0)

for i in site:
  lista_de_ip.append(i[-1][0])
lista_de_ip = list(set(lista_de_ip))

print(lista_de_ip)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc testou esse código? Ele realmente funciona? Pra mim aqui ele só gerou uma lista com um IP e um MAC address...

Comment: Sim Luiz, testei e realmente funciona! 
Gerou algum erro pra você? Pra mim ele retorna um IPV4 do facebook e outro é um IPV6(não MAC address)
Coloquei a saída do meu terminal, na resposta  acima. No meu caso apresenta estes devido aos caches do facebook em minha cidade, na sua pode ser diferente.

Comment: Vc tem razão, é um IPV6 e não um MAC address. Desculpe pelo equívoco.

Comment: certo! 
E você precisa dos IP's em outro formato?